# OAuth and OauthLite diffrence

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I am a beginner to OAuth - so i want to know what is the difference between Oauth and Oauth   Lite

Answer (score 1):

[OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) is an authorization protocol.

[OAuth::Lite](https://github.com/lyokato/p5-oauth-lite) is a perl library implementing the OAuth 1.0 protocol. If you develop a web service that should provide OAuth authorization or if you develop a perl application that should connect to some OAuth provider, you can use this library.

For OAuth 2.0 there's respectively the [OAuth::Lite2](https://github.com/lyokato/p5-oauth-lite2) library.